# Two axis plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Example I want to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0ZFA.png) I need to plot a two axis plot in R with ggplot2. The first y axis goes from -10 to 10, and the second from 0 to 10. I add an example. Please, let me know if there is a way to do it with ggplot2.

I used this code, but the result makes the first axis from -5 to 10, and the second, from 5 to 10. I want to get the breaks I define earlier.

```
df %>% filter(Country == "Chile" & year >= 1973) %>% ggplot(aes(x = year)) +
geom_line(aes(y = polity2, colour = "Polity 2")) + geom_line(aes(y = gee_totGDP,colour = "gee_totGDP")) + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*-1,name = "gee_totGDP")) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```

Comment: Please share your dataset using `dput(df)`. Just copy the output of that func.

Answer (score 0):

I generated some fake data with four rows based on your example image.

To make the plot, I set the limits for the first axis using the `limits()` argument. Then I set up the second axis using a transformation formula, like you attempted. The transformation should be axis2 = (axis1 + 10)/2.

```r
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- tibble(year = seq(1985, 2000, 5),
             ed = c(6, 6, 8, 5),
             polity = c(-10, -10, -8, -8))

    df %>%
             ggplot(aes(x = year)) +
             geom_line(aes(y = polity)) + 
             geom_line(aes(y = ed)) +
             scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10),
                                sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. + 10)/2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_y_continuous()` for both axis as the following:

```
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = polity2, color = "Polity 2")) +
 geom_line(aes(y = gee_totGDP, color = "gee_totGDP")) +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10), name = "Polity 2") +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = 
  "gee_totGDP")) +
 scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```